# What does "situational associativity between nouns" mean?

Tags: terminology

I am reading some [slides of an NLP course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-864-advanced-natural-language-processing-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec01.pdf). Slide 25 mentions:

> situational associativity between nouns (the score of the football game).

What does "situational associativity between nouns" mean?

Comment: For instance, the noun _score_ in this context means the final score, a total of all the individual instances of _score_ by both teams, produced as a pair of numbers. An NLP program would ideally be primed for that sequence of numbers in this context, and would identify the parts. See Framenet.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks, feel free to convert it into an answer!